# ngRoute not working in Spring Boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am developing Single Page Application using Spring Boot and Angular JS. I setup Rest Controller, Index page, and few HTML pages. When I run the application, Spring Boot should load index page and redirect to login page on load based ngRoute configuration. Instead, it loads index page and does not redirect to the login page. Code uploaded in Github: [Click here for Github Repository](https://github.com/jpavanaryan/SpringBootDemo)

**GreetingController:**

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class GreetingController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Map<String,Object> home() 
    {
        Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        model.put("id", "Test Id");
        model.put("content", "Hello World");
        return model;
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-cookies.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" > </script>

<script>

var App = angular.module('loginPage',['ngRoute']);  
App.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider,$locationProvider) 
{

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'loginController',
          controllerAs: 'controller'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'loginController',
          controllerAs: 'controller'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'homeController',
          controllerAs: 'controller'
    }).
  otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(
            {
              enabled: true,
              requireBase: false,
              //rewriteLinks: false
            });
    //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

  });

App.controller('homeController',['$window','$scope','$http',function($window,$scope,$http)
{
    $scope.message="Home Controller";
    $scope.validateLoginDetails=function()
    {
        $http.get('/greeting/').then(
        function success(response) 
        {
            $scope.responseText = response.data;
          },

        function failure(response)
          {
                $scope.responseText = response.data; 
          });

    };
}]);

App.controller('loginController',['$window','$scope','$http',function($window,$scope,$http)
    {
    $scope.message="Login Controller";
        $scope.validateLoginDetails=function()
        {
            $http.get('/greeting/').then(
            function success(response) 
            {
                $scope.responseText = response.data;
              },

            function failure(response)
              {
                    $scope.responseText = response.data; 
              });

        };
    }]);

App.controller('indexController',['$window','$scope','$http',function($window,$scope,$http)
    {
        $scope.message="Index Controller";
        $scope.validateLoginDetails=function()
        {
            $http.get('/greeting/').then(
            function success(response) 
            {
                $scope.responseText = response.data;
              },

            function failure(response)
              {
                    $scope.responseText = response.data; 
              });

        };
    }]);

</script>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="loginPage">

<div class="container" data-ng-controller="indexController">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <a href="login" >Click here for login page</a>
   <h1>Inside Index Page</h1>

  <p>Response:  {{responseText}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-cookies.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" > </script>

<script>
var cookies = document.cookie;
console.log('Login Page Cookies :'+cookies)


var App = angular.module('loginPage',['ngRoute','ngResource','ngCookies']); 
App.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) 
{
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'validateForm'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'validateForm'
    }).otherwise('/');

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

  });

App.controller('validateForm',['$window','$scope','$http','$cookies',function($window,$scope,$http,$cookies)
{
    $scope.validateLoginDetails=function()
    {
        $http.get('/greeting/').then(
        function success(response) 
        {
            $scope.responseText = response.data;
          },

        function failure(response)
          {
                $scope.responseText = response.data; 
          });

    };
}]);

</script>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="loginPage">

<div class="container" data-ng-controller="validateForm">
  <h2>Login</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Username:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user_name" name="user_name"  id="user_name" placeholder="Enter Username" name="email" style="max-width:700px">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password"  data-ng-model="user_password" name="user_password" id="user_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd"  style="max-width:700px">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember-me"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary content_login btn-lg"  data-ng-click="validateLoginDetails()">Login</button>
    <br/> <br/>
        <a class="col-md-offset-2" style="margin-left: 2px" href="forgotpassword.html">Forgot password?</a> <br/> <br/>
        <a class="col-md-offset-2" style="margin-left: 2px" href="register.html">Request New Account</a>

  <p>Response:  {{responseText}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly i don't see `ng-view` directive in main html file. and don't need put `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in template like `login.html` file.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What's the relevance of the greeting controller to your question? Why should Spring redirect? Why do you think Spring Boot cares about the configuration of the angular routing? Why do you have two different angular HTML pages in the first place? And finally, what are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: I was developing Restful services with Spring Boot. Accessing http://localhost:8080/greeting returns JSON output. Then I wanted to implement login page, home page with Angular JS. So, I am redirecting to /login to on loading index page. Except Rest Controller, everything explained in above question if you had gone through it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hadi** is right. **ngRoute** works with [ngView](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView). You should have `<div ng-view> </div` in your HTML. ngRoute gets data from REST Controller and displays in **div** tag associated with **ngView**. If you want to redirect to different page, then you should consider using

`$window.location.href="/login.html";`.

Let me know if this helps. Please refer [Angular JS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) for more information about **ngView**